C4 picasso air suspension woes - want to delve deeper
C4 Picasso suspension has been done to death over the years and I have myself switched it out, but I want to know more about how its setup. There are guides that explain about taking measurements and doing some calcs and entering the information BUT what is this actually telling the ECU to do? There are a number of parameters too i.e. initial height, reference height so when you enter the data in Lexia what of these parameters are you affecting please? I also see a situation where one sensor reads -40mm and the other +25cm. Assuming the sensors were all good should these be comparable? A few last things, the guide says measure the car and do the calcs and enter the values but what if its too high in the first place? What if you want to have the car ride a little lower how would you enter values to fool the car into doing that? Thanks in advance

You stated ... "-40mm and the other +25cm" ... +25cm is nearly 10". Even most truck lifts don't go that high. Did you mean +25 mm?

yes i did mean  mm, and these are just example numbers to illustrate the delta
